# Importing Parent function data in child php oop

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to learn simple method of php oop by calling parent function data in child.
However somewhere I am making mistake.

```
class name{
    var $firstname;
    var $lastname;
    var $name;
    public function name($firstname, $lastname){
        $this->firstname=$firstname;
        $this->lastname=$lastname;
        $this->name=$this->firstname." ".$this->lastname;
        return $this->name;
    }
}
class sentence extends name{
    var $name;
    var $letter;
    function sentence(){
        $this->letter="My name is ";
        echo $this->letter.$this->name;
    }
}
$name=new name(ABC, Xyz);
$letter=new sentence();
```

I have created one calls to get name input and another child class to write the sentence. However not able to call the name in child.

Comment: throws away that "php4 for beginner" book

Comment: Try $letter->sentence(); and no need tomake an object of name class. @Daksh

Comment: I think it's hard to explain in detail here. You should learn OOP carefully again.
http://phpio.net/s/ru3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class name
{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $name;
    public function name($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->name = $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname;

        return $this->name;
    }
}
class sentence extends name
{
    public $name;
    public $letter;
    public function greeting()
    {
        $this->letter = 'My name is ';
        echo $this->letter.$this->name;
    }
}
//$name=new name(ABC, Xyz);
$letter = new sentence('ABC', 'Xyz');
$letter->greeting();
```

Thanks to @ManhNguyen

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix since thats probably what you want.

```
<?php
class name {

private $firstname;
private $lastname;
private $name;
private $sentence;

public function __construct($firstname, $lastname){
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->lastname = $lastname;
    $this->name = $firstname . " " . $lastname;
    $this->sentence = "My name is : " . $this->name;

}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function getSentence(){
    return $this->sentence;
 }
}

$instance = new name("test","lastname");

echo $instance->getSentence();
?>
```